# Contact form 7 required date field validation error

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

My form fields code is,

Event-Datum*

[date* eventDate class:event-date date-format:mm/dd/yy min-date:today]

here date is required field but it doesn't validate this required date field.

Answer (score 1):

`date-format` is not a valid parameter in the [Contact Form 7 date field](http://contactform7.com/date-field/). Also, the `min-date` parameter is invalid. Instead use, `min`.

So, the correct code will be 
Event-Datum* [date* eventDate class:event-date min:today]